# how can i solve a slim4 sapphirecat error

Tags: php, html, xampp, composer-php, slim-4

i have been working on a librery proyect with slim4. i realized a merge from github and the the proyect broke.
the error is :
Fatal error: Type of Sapphirecat

```
Fatal error: Type of Sapphirecat\Slim4HttpInteropAdapter\GuzzlePsr7v1Factory::$responseFactoryClass must be string (as in class Slim\Factory\Psr17\Psr17Factory) in C:\xampp\htdocs\libreria_alejandria\vendor\sapphirecat\slim4-http-interop-adapter\src\GuzzlePsr7v1Factory.php on line 14
```

i have reinstalled the slim requirements, but i get the same

Comment: Restore the last known good configuration and the error should be gone. If that is - for some unfortunate circumstances - not a n option, contact the author of the library and negotiate the conditions of your support options.

Comment: "i realized a merge from github and the the proyect broke" - why not revert that merge? Why not use any kind of CI pipeline that checks your application for issues before merging?

Answer (score -2):

As you await a fix from the vendor, **Temporarily** edit the file GuzzlePsr7v1Factory.php from

```
    /** @var string */
    protected static $responseFactoryClass = 'Http\Factory\Guzzle\ResponseFactory';
    /** @var string */
    protected static $streamFactoryClass = 'Http\Factory\Guzzle\StreamFactory';
    /** @var string */
    protected static $serverRequestCreatorClass = 'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest';
    /** @var string */
    protected static $serverRequestCreatorMethod = 'fromGlobals';
```

to

```
    /** @var string */
    protected static string $responseFactoryClass = 'Http\Factory\Guzzle\ResponseFactory';
    /** @var string */
    protected static string $streamFactoryClass = 'Http\Factory\Guzzle\StreamFactory';
    /** @var string */
    protected static string $serverRequestCreatorClass = 'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\ServerRequest';
    /** @var string */
    protected static string $serverRequestCreatorMethod = 'fromGlobals';
```

i.e. add `string` after `static` of each of the class members.

Comment: Editing files in the `vendor` directory is never a good idea

Comment: Keyword `Temporarily`. As he waits for fix from the vendor

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).